# How to fix this carousel issue in bootstrap4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Hi i am trying to implement multi item Carousel moving at one item at once click. **But in my case when i click right arrow it total slide changed**. for your reference i have mentioned my referred link below. so please if you find out the mistake in my code please let me know.

**HTML**

```
  <div class="row">
      <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <div class="d-none d-lg-block">
              <div class="slide-box">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/285/200/?image=0&random" alt="First slide">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/285/200/?image=1&random" alt="First slide">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/285/200/?image=2&random" alt="First slide">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/285/200/?image=3&random" alt="First slide">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="d-none d-lg-block">
              <div class="slide-box">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/285/200/?image=4&random" alt="Second slide">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/285/200/?image=5&random" alt="Second slide">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/285/200/?image=6&random" alt="Second slide">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/285/200/?image=7&random" alt="Second slide">
              </div>
            </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.carousel {
  width: 100%;
  }

  .slide-box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  }
.slide-box img {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 25%;
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  max-width: 1600px;
}
.carousel-caption {
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
padding: 20px;
border-radius: .5rem;
}
```

referred  link [CodePen](https://codepen.io/FrankieDoodie/pen/gdabrR)

**OUTPUT image**
[image: Output image]

Comment: What are you expecting??

Comment: I guess, you need to add one image per slide! Putting all 4 images under `<div class="carousel-item active">` will slide all the images together.

Comment: @JoykalInfotech Am expecting like  multi item carousel moving at one item at once click

Comment: Then the suggestion by @varit will work for you.

Comment: @varit05 Can u please tell me how to do it .

Comment: It ain't that hard to add images in different divs, see there you see the answer, so simple.

Comment: @Jaykal infotech Actually am expecting like this  codeply.com/go/JEAsn1lz3a

Answer (score 0):

@smithhari, you need to include every single image in side a `<div class="carousel-item"></div>`. In your code you have few images inside each  tags. That's "carousel-item" class. Because of this you only have two slides, each including multiple images. Create a div tag with "carousel-item" for each img tag.

```
<div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://picsum.photos/285/200/?image=0&random" alt="First slide">
</div>
<div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://picsum.photos/240/200/?image=0&random" alt="Second slide">
</div>
<div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://picsum.photos/270/200/?image=1&random" alt="Third slide">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried as u said but it occupy hole page but multiple carousel was not displaying it.

Comment: @smithhari https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qgYGZB - is that what you were trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am actually expecting output like this codeply.com/go/JEAsn1lz3a

Answer (score 0):

Check if following works for you or not
[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MLGdbz)

```js
$('#carouselExample').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {

  
    var $e = $(e.relatedTarget);
    var idx = $e.index();
    var itemsPerSlide = 4;
    var totalItems = $('.carousel-item').length;
    
    if (idx >= totalItems-(itemsPerSlide-1)) {
        var it = itemsPerSlide - (totalItems - idx);
        for (var i=0; i<it; i++) {
            // append slides to end
            if (e.direction=="left") {
                $('.carousel-item').eq(i).appendTo('.carousel-inner');
            }
            else {
                $('.carousel-item').eq(0).appendTo('.carousel-inner');
            }
        }
    }
});


  $('#carouselExample').carousel({ 
                interval: 4000
        });


  $(document).ready(function() {
/* show lightbox when clicking a thumbnail */
    $('a.thumb').click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      var content = $('.modal-body');
      content.empty();
        var title = $(this).attr("title");
        $('.modal-title').html(title);        
        content.html($(this).html());
        $(".modal-profile").modal({show:true});
    });

  });
```

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {

    /* show 3 items */
    .carousel-inner .active,
    .carousel-inner .active + .carousel-item,
    .carousel-inner .active + .carousel-item + .carousel-item,
    .carousel-inner .active + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item  {
        display: block;
    }
    
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left),
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left) + .carousel-item,
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left) + .carousel-item + .carousel-item,
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left) + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        transition: none;
    }
    
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next,
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
      position: relative;
      transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    
    .carousel-inner .active.carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: -25%;
        z-index: -1;
        display: block;
        visibility: visible;
    }
    
    /* left or forward direction */
    .active.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left,
    .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item,
    .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item + .carousel-item,
    .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item,
    .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        position: relative;
        transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
        visibility: visible;
    }
    
    /* farthest right hidden item must be abso position for animations */
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: -1;
        display: block;
        visibility: visible;
    }
    
    /* right or prev direction */
    .active.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right,
    .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item,
    .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item + .carousel-item,
    .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item,
    .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        position: relative;
        transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
        visibility: visible;
        display: block;
        visibility: visible;
    }

}

 /* Bootstrap Lightbox using Modal */

#profile-grid { overflow: auto; white-space: normal; } 
#profile-grid .profile { padding-bottom: 40px; }
#profile-grid .panel { padding: 0 }
#profile-grid .panel-body { padding: 15px }
#profile-grid .profile-name { font-weight: bold; }
#profile-grid .thumbnail {margin-bottom:6px;}
#profile-grid .panel-thumbnail { overflow: hidden; }
#profile-grid .img-rounded { border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="carouselExample" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="9000">
        <div class="carousel-inner row w-100 mx-auto" role="listbox">
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-3  active">
               <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-thumbnail">
                    <a href="#" title="image 1" class="thumb">
                      <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="https://picsum.photos/285/200/?image=0&random" alt="slide 1">
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-3 ">
               <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-thumbnail">
                    <a href="#" title="image 3" class="thumb">
                     <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="https://picsum.photos/285/200/?image=1&random" alt="slide 2">
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-3 ">
               <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-thumbnail">
                    <a href="#" title="image 4" class="thumb">
                     <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="https://picsum.photos/285/200/?image=2&random" alt="slide 3">
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-3 ">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-thumbnail">
                    <a href="#" title="image 5" class="thumb">
                     <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="https://picsum.photos/285/200/?image=3&random" alt="slide 4">
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-3 ">
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-thumbnail">
                    <a href="#" title="image 6" class="thumb">
                      <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="https://picsum.photos/285/200/?image=4&random" alt="slide 5">
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-3 ">
               <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-thumbnail">
                    <a href="#" title="image 7" class="thumb">
                      <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="https://picsum.photos/285/200/?image=5&random" alt="slide 6">
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-3 ">
               <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-thumbnail">
                    <a href="#" title="image 8" class="thumb">
                      <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="https://picsum.photos/285/200/?image=6&random" alt="slide 7">
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="carousel-item col-md-3  ">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-thumbnail">
                    <a href="#" title="image 2" class="thumb">
                     <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="https://picsum.photos/285/200/?image=7&random" alt="slide 8">
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExample" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next text-faded" href="#carouselExample" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My expecting like this codeply.com/go/JEAsn1lz3a can u please look in to it.

Comment: @smithhari Great!! so you found the answer for your question.

Comment: Did you checked the codepen link given in my answer it dose same, check if that works for you.

Comment: Codepen link ? can u please share that link